# npx webpack no production bundle

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

When I try to make development build (I set `DEV = true`), it works perfectly.
But when I make production build, bundle did not appear in `js` folder.

In same time, I discover if I replace my application with an empty stub, it work:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
//import A from "./application";

ReactDOM.render(<div/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I have list of error from tslint, but it work with development build. I mean, bundle appear, application work without errors in runtime. But production build just did not appear. Is it possible to `force` it somehow? Or what I'm doing wrong?

There is my webpack config:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require('path');

const DEV = false;

const out = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../js'),
  },
};

if(!DEV) {
  out.mode = "production";
  out.watch = false;
} else {
  out.devtool = "eval"
  out.mode = "development"
  out.watch = true;
  out.watchOptions = {
    poll: true,
    ignored: /node_modules/
  };
  out.plugins.push(new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
    filename: 'main.js.map',
    exclude: ['vendor.js']}))
}
module.exports = out;
```

and my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [

  ]
}
```

I run it with `npx webpack`

Comment: Do you have a reproducible repo or you can create a new one with piece of code?

Comment: Currently trying to fix all errors from tslint

Answer (score 1):

I change my tsconfig file to this one

```
{


 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    //"noEmit": true,

    "module": "esnext",


    "outDir": "../",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    // "module": "es6",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
  ]
}
```

fix all errors from ts lint

and after I comment "noEmit":true it suddenly start to work with production mode as well. Can't explain what happen exactly.